# How can I save a cookie with the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was planning to have a drag and drop note feature in my website, and have it saved in a javascript cookie. Also, I wanted to save the textarea as a variable, and the variable as a cookie... I don't want to use local storage. If you see on the part where the div element is, there is a button. I don't really know how to put a variable from the textbox on the cookie, so when you click on the variable, it stores the text inside the textbox as a variable, and then it stores the variable as a cookie. So, when you reload the page, it inserts the cookie into the textarea. 
I wanted to do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#notes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#notesheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>


<div id="notes">
  <div id="notesheader">Notes</div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="document.cookie = "username= Notes";">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("notes"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>
<button onclick="hideshow()">Notes</button>
<script>
function hideshow() {
  var x = document.getElementById("notes");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Did you manage to get this work as expected?

Comment: yep, it worked... Thanks!

Comment: Cool, so please don't forget to mark it as an answer to help other peeps in the community to find their answer if they facing the same issue. :D If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/762001) might help.

Comment: Ok, I marked your answer correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a `textarea` value you just have to query it and get its value. then you should use `document.cookie` to set the desired cookie.

### Create cookie

So whenever save button gets clicked you should run a function like this:

HMTL

```html
<div id="notes">
  <div id="notesheader">Notes</div>
  <textarea id="notes" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="saveNotes();">Save</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
function saveNotes() {
  document.cookie = "textAreaValue=" + document.getElementById("notes").value
}
```

### Read cookie

To read the cookie from the browser **you need to do is to get `document.cookie` value and inject your desired value from it** (Since it keeps all the domain cookie). Getting cookies by name is a bit tricky since `document.cookie` will return all the cookies in the domain, so we should define two functions for this cause. First a function to get cookie by the desired name and another function to catch the window load and then load a cookie to our elements.

Your code should be something like this:

```js
function getCookie(cookieName) {
  var name = cookieName + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

window.onload = function() { // window.onload will indicate when the window is loaded do this function
  var textAreaFromCookie = getCookie("textAreaValue")

  if (textAreaFromCookie) {
    document.getElementById('notes').value = textAreaFromCookie
  }
};
```

Comment: @Element.js If you set an `id` for your `textarea` it should be straight forward. Assume we set `id="note"` for it, so the query will be something like this `document.getElementById('note').value`.

Comment: Oh yeah... that works too, but I wanted to have a feature where it would take the cookie, and then put it into the textarea...

Thanks!

Comment: @Element.js For this cause, you just have to check if `document.cookie` exists then put the related value into your `textarea`. I can update the answer to illustrate it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used a `"` inside a string consisting of `"`s without escaping. Use a string with `'`s or escape the quotes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#notes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#notesheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>


<div id="notes">
  <div id="notesheader">Notes</div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="document.cookie = 'username= Notes';">Save</button>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("notes"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>
<button onclick="hideshow()">Notes</button>
<script>
function hideshow() {
  var x = document.getElementById("notes");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```